# ThreeJS определить условие столкновения 2-ух объектов?

Tags: three.js, webgl

Есть 2 объекта в пространстве.
Имеются у каждого координаты.

Какое условие соблюдается при столкновении объектов?
Возможно есть какие-нибудь библиотеки.
Лично мои домыслы были:
z , y , z сравнивать, но опять же тут надо учитывать ширину\высоту объекта я думаю, чтобы производить сравнения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С ThreeJS не знаком. Попробуй, может, [box2d-js](http://box2d-js.sourceforge.net/) как-нибудь прикрутить удастся (или м.б. уже кто-то прикручивал, найдешь).

Еще, думаю, если представить каждый объект в виде параллелепипепеда или шара (или совокупность оных простых форм - не знаю, что у тебя там за объекты), то можно будет попробовать рассчитать их столкновение исходя из их радиусов, длин, высот, углов поворота и т.п.

Либо, что по-моему проще, - старым "дедовским" способом, создавая виртуальный массив (объект) заполненных точек пространства вида `t_X_Y_Z="_id_объекта_которым_занята_или_пустое";` (что-то вроде `{t_10_240_110="obj1", t_20_240_110="obj1", t_20_250_110=""/*Пустой*/,...}` - причем, лучше иметь один глобальный массив, где записаны все, и отдельные "частные" массивы для каждого из объектов, для быстрого доступа вида `{t_10_240_110=[10,240,110], t_20_240_110=[20,240,210],..}` ), и перезаписывая их при перемещении объекта, а перед перемещением, соответственно проверяя те точки, в которых он должен оказаться не заняты ли они уже кем-то (к примеру, если объект должен сместиться на 10 условных единиц по `x` то,запускаешь переборку упомянутого выше частного массива (назовем его, для примера, `obj1`) и сравниваешь его увеличенные на 10 значения по `X`  со значениями из глобального (`global1`)

```
var stolknovenie=false;
for(var i in obj){
    var X= obj[i][0], Y= obj[i][1], Z= obj[i][2]; 
    var newC = global1['t_'+(X+10)+'_'+Y+'_'+Z];
    if(typeof newC!="undefined" && newC!=="" && newC!=="obj1"){stolknovenie=true;}
    /*т.е. если данная координата зарегистрирована, не пуста и не указано, что она занята самим же этим объектом, то значит в ней во что-то врежимся*/
   //В более сложном случае, можно использовать один или несколько вложенных циклов, для проверки, к примеру,  всех значений от X до X+n, при изменении Y от Y до Y+n ....
}

 if (stolknovenie == false){
    /*Если ни с чем не сталкиваемся, то выполняем перемещение объекта на новое место и перезаписываем новые значения в глобальный и частный массивы*/
 } else {
    /*Что происходит при столкновении*/
 }
```

Понятно, что на практике, данная функция в итоге может получиться и более сложной и навороченной (например, для сдвига не на все расстояние, а лишь до препятствия, и поведение в зависимости от того, в какой точке произошло столкновение...), но суть та же: регистрация занятых и свободных точек (кстати, иногда целесообразно регистрировать/проверять не каждую точку (пиксель или какой-то другой минимум), но, к примеру, с шагом в 10 или еще в какое-нибудь значение, если не нужна сверхбольшая точность, чтобы не забивать память слишком большим количеством переменных)

В общем, если ничего не найдешь - м.б. это хоть как-то пригодится

Answer (score 1):

```
var ray = new THREE.Raycaster( position, vectors[i].sub(position).normalize() );
var intersects = ray.intersectObjects( objs );
if ( intersects.length > 0 && intersects[0].distance <= 10) 
{
    //Объекты находятся на дистанции меньше заданной
}
```

Где "position" - это позиция проверяемого объекта, массив "vectors" - массив лучей выпущенных из объекта (лучше сказать из этой позиции) в разные стороны. Массив "objs" - это коллекция объектов которые могут столкнуться с выбранным объектом (если какой либо объект не поместить в этот массив, он будет игнорироваться). И важный момент, intersects[0].distance - это дистанция между объектами.

Comment: Этот же механизм используется для выделения объекта курсором мыши. В этом случае в качестве "position" - позиция курсора мыши на экране, а массив лучей (в этом случае он один) - камера, используемая в сцене.